# change href behavior when using boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Because I am not a web expert, I just downloaded [this template](https://www.freshdesignweb.com/demo/template/ubusina/) to work on it with the minimum changes (only text, pics etc.).

The template I am using include `bootsrap` and it gives good result. The problem is that I am trying to add a link to a new page and, for a reason I ignore this won't work.

I think that there is something in `bootsrap.js` or an other  `.js` file that tell the browser to stay in the same page even when we use `href`.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem here? And how can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your code? specifically the link you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 20 of the custom.js file is blocking the links
change the line as under:

```
            //smoothscroll
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Yup, the prevent default will keep your hrefs from going anywhere with that script. I assume lucky just commented that out. Seems good to me.

Comment: Thanks I gived a try but that don't work, I think that there is  other `preventDefault` in the other javascripts